# how to add space between 3 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default bootstrap doesn't add spaces between columns but I want to control it. Here is what I have tried

```
<style>
.col-md-12{
    background: red;
}
.col-md-4{
    background: lime;
}

</style>
 <div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            Some Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

As result I get this[image]

But I want to achieve this

[image]

I don't want to add space between the container and the columns. I just want to add space between the columns.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Add First and Last class from div

```
.first{
    padding-left:0px !important; 
  }

 .last{
    padding-right:0px !important; 
  }
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/PN8edIkglD)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10970/)**

You need to override the existing class by adding !important (but its not a good practice).

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 5px  !important;
}
```

If you want to give any specific class like this

```
.pad_s.col-xs-1, .pad_s.col-xs-2, ...{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 5px  !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container padd_s">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see updated code as per your requirement [fiddle][1]

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/8ggkvwd9/`<div class="row no-gutter>"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this example on codepen([DEMO](http://codepen.io/vubon/pen/EjJjGW)). I hope that you will solve your problem.

Just copy the link on your browser and I am very sorry that I can't give the link correctly here .Because codepen.io may be does not support stackoverflow .

```
.first{margin-left:-15px;}
.third{margin-left: 15px;}
```